# How to send a file uploaded by javascript and get it received in a flask app and send it as post request to another server?

Tags: javascript, python, rest, flask

When i try to send a post request from flask using the file, which is received via the ajax request from client side, I am getting an exception:'too many values to unpack (expected 2)

1. I have a client side app which uploads a file(Javascript).
2. I have my server code which acts as a proxy which deals with all external server calls. The uploaded file gets send to this server as a post request from client side.
3. Now i need to send this file received in my server to an external server as a post request using requests module in python.

I am stuck with an exception when i am doing step 3. 
I am not sure if it is the right way to post such files as i am new to flask. Please give some inputs which might help.

1. Client side code

   ```
   $('input[type="file"]').change(function (e) {
   var formData = new FormData(e.target.files[0]);
   var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
   var fileType = e.target.name;

   var settings = {
       "async": true,
       "crossDomain": true,
       "url": "/upload?file_name="+fileName+"&file_type="+fileType,
       "method": "POST",
       "contentType": false,
       "cache": false,
       "processData": false,
       "data": formData
     };

     $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
     });
   });
   ```
2. Flask code

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def uploadToExternalServer():
        if request.method == "POST":
            try:
                file_content=request.files['file']
                file_type= request.args.get('file_type')
                file_name= request.args.get('file_name')
                url="url to post with params"
                response = requests.post(url, auth=('usr', 'pwd!'),files=file_content)   
                return r
            except Exception as e:
                logging.info(e.args[0])
```

`Expected:`

Should be able to successfully post the file to the external server

`Actual:`

Getting an exception at post request as :'too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Where are you getting the error specifically? Are you able to share which line is producing the error. It is usually related to reading tuples.

Comment: @calestini: ya sure. I am receiving it at                 
response = requests.post(url, auth=('usr', 'pwd!'),files=file_content)

Comment: Have you inspected your `file_content` to see if it is `Dictionary of files to multipart upload ({filename: content}).` ?

Comment: @calestini: It is not int he form you specified. Its contents are as below
``content_length:0
content_type:'text/plain'
filename:'test.txt'
headers:Headers([('Content-Disposition', 'form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"'), ('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
mimetype:'text/plain'
mimetype_params:{}
name:'file'
stream:<tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile object at 0x112d47a58>
_parsed_content_type:('text/plain', {})``

Comment: That is probably why @Binoy. It is lookinf for a format of `dict`. I would recommend you to go through the documentation and see some examples on how to pass files

Comment: I fixed it now. I am able to send the file now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation of [Requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.request)

I think your problem is that you are trying to do your post passing the file like an object, and the param expects an dictionary.

> **files** – (optional) Dictionary of 'name': file-like-objects (or {'name': file-tuple}) for multipart encoding upload. file-tuple can be a 2-tuple ('filename', fileobj), 3-tuple ('filename', fileobj, 'content_type') or a 4-tuple ('filename', fileobj, 'content_type', custom_headers), where 'content-type' is a string defining the content type of the given file and custom_headers a dict-like object containing additional headers to add for the file.

Comment: I guess that is the issue. I am trying to fix it and will update once it is working. Thank you